# Configure Privacy Statement link for Azure B2B invite

Tags: azure, privacy, b2b, azure-ad-b2b

We are inviting the external users using Graph Api B2B to our tenant, When the user tries to log in to our application, it will ask the user to review the permission. On that screen, we need to provide the link for our organization's Privacy.

[image]

I know they're an option to configure this but somehow I am not able to find the option in the Azure portal. Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add your organization's privacy information in the **Properties** area of Azure AD.

1.Sign in to the Azure portal as a tenant administrator.

2.On the left navbar, select **Azure Active Directory**, and then select **Properties**.The Properties area appears.

3.Add your privacy info for your employees.

[image]

For more information, please see the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-properties-area).